# Multiple interfaces and networks with Netplan: can't ping local network

Tags: ubuntu, routing, netplan

My netplan config, with multiple interfaces and networks, works perfectly apart from ping to (or from?) local network.

Here's my setup:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
      - 172.16.1.114/16
      match:
          macaddress: 00:50:56:aa:00:1d
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.16.1.11
        - 172.16.1.20
        search:
        - domain.com
      set-name: production
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.16.1.1
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
          table: 800
      routing-policy:
        - from: 0.0.0.0/0
          table: 800
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
      - 172.21.2.114/16
      match:
          macaddress: 00:50:56:aa:6f:ed
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.16.1.11
        - 172.16.1.20
        search:
        - domain.com
      set-name: quality
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.21.1.1
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
          table: 801
      routing-policy:
        - from: 0.0.0.0/0
          table: 801
    ens224:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
      - 172.21.1.114/16
      match:
          macaddress: 00:50:56:aa:16:92
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.16.1.11
        - 172.16.1.20
        search:
        - domain.com
      set-name: development
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.21.1.1
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
          table: 802
      routing-policy:
        - from: 0.0.0.0/0
          table: 802
```

Thanks for your help!

By the way, is there a way to choose which device to send packets FROM, for troubleshooting purposes?